# An application running via jar cannot connect to MySQL NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-256 MessageDigest

Tags: java, mysql, exception

There is an application written in Kotlin TornadoFX (==java / JavaFX), if I run it via main or any other class everything works fine, dB connection and queries work, but if I collect a jar file (in my case, I collected both regular jar and shadowjar) and run it, it gives an error:

```java
java.sql.SQLException: ASSERTION FAILED: Exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-256 MessageDigest not available that should not be thrown, was thrown at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(
NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at dataBase.DatabaseHandler.getAuth(
DatabaseHandler.kt:128) at LogIn$root$1.invoke(LogIn.kt:18) at LogIn$root$1.invoke(LogIn.kt:12) at tornadofx.LayoutsKt.borderpane(Layouts.kt:465) at LogIn.(LogIn.kt:14) at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) at
tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:432) at tornadofx.FXKt.find$default(FX.kt:406) at tornadofx.App.start(App.kt:81) at Main.start(Main.kt:9) at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863) at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326) at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294) at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95) at
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the LogIn class, there is a query in the DB, Respectively, in the DatabaseHandler class, this query is implemented.

In what cases this error occurs and How to handle it?

P.S.: If you remove requests to the dB, the jar file will also start and work, the error is specifically related to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the program cannot connect to some libraries (meaning other jar files or other dependent projects in your IDE)
That is hinted by the words in the beginning `NoSuchAlgorithmException` and  `MessageDigest not available`

This is the case, when libraries or dependent projects are missing in the jar file, or in the  PATH  of the VM when it is running the jar file.

In Eclipse, when creating a "Runnable jar file" you can choose whether dependent libraries should be packaged along with your code.

Then without Eclipse, you can modify the execution of the jar file in the command line
`java -jar ...`
you could add arguments that point to more paths, where the other libraries or project sources are.